# Is there a way to force someone to enter a non-empty value/string in a cell in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a certain cell to be mandatory in a Google Spreadsheet. Can this be done? I looked through the `Data > Validation` and the criteria does not have anything for checking null.

Comment: Do you really mean a column and not a cell? I.e., are you okay with user putting something _somewhere_ in a column, no matter what row?

Comment: Sorry. I meant a cell. Thanks for the clarifying !

Comment: @Jeeka Required questions in Google Forms or events of Google Apps Script could work for certain uses cases. Please add more details about of the use case or steps that you expect that the users of your spreadsheet will follow.

Comment: @Rubén: Thanks, I will try that. Here is the use case. When a user skips entering information in a particular cell (say A2), he/she should be warned (i can do this by using conditional formatting), but i want to make the user enter some text in the cell before moving to the next cell

Comment: @Jeeka without more details, I think that the easier solution is to use a Google Form with the first question set as required and the answers destination set to a Google Sheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, Data Validation is applied only to user-entered data. If there is no data in a cell, validation rules do not run on it. See [Empty data cell validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24995055) on Stack Overflow.

Some surrogates, which can be used in combination:

1. Conditional formatting. Make the background red if the cell is empty.
2. A message in another cell, such as `=IF(A2="","Cell A2 is required","")` entered in A3.  This is effective together with (1), as it provides verbal explanation of the red background.
3. Data Validation applied to another cell. For example: A1 is the heading "Amount", and A2 is where you expect the amount to be entered. You can apply Data Validation to  A1 in the form "Custom Formula" `=NOT(ISBLANK(A2))`. The drawback is that it's A1 that will show warning, not A2. And it's impossible to *reject* input in this way, since input happens in A2.

As   noted at the beginning, the natural attempt of applying custom formula `=NOT(ISBLANK(A2))` to A2 itself won't work because the validity is not checked while the cell is empty.